# Running docker inside an (ubuntu) vagrant box on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, docker

I've just recently been introduced to Docker, my knowledge of how it works is quite limited and I'm currently constrained by time in deciding on which way to go.

- Was running Windows 10 Home, could not install Docker for Windows, installed Docker Toolbox but was not able to get up and running easily
- Upgraded to Windows 10 Professional. Installed Docker for Windows. After a couple of hours it seemed I had things working. Hyper-V enabled means my old vagrant machines (using Virtualbox) no longer work. Docker did not seem to have any network (internet) connectivity. Gave up for now, disabled Hyper-V, back to vagrant

I've been thinking that I could setup a vagrant box, or just an Ubuntu VM, using Virtualbox, and perhaps get Docker up and running on that.

This is for the purpose of working on a PHP7/Nginx/Laravel application

My questions are - should this work ok? Would there be performance issues? My experience with Ubuntu is that it's a lot more straightforward to get these kinds of things working, for example, Docker, than it is on Windows.

Furthermore, what could I look for in a pre-existing vagrant box, that would allow me to get setup as quickly as possible with Docker (running on the vagrant box)?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.kenrelax.com/windows-10-vagrant-virtualbox-docker-setup/ you may take a look this website how to setup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. The performance of the VM will depend on the amount of RAM that you give to it and the demands of your application.

A vagrant box running Ubuntu Xenial will be enough to get you started.

Install Docker https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-server-ubuntu